# Is an WLS estimator unbiased, when wrong weights are used?

Tags: regression, variance, unbiased-estimator, weighted-regression

It is clear that the WLS estimators are consistent if the "wrong" weights used aren't correlated with the explanatory variables. However, I don't know whether this also holds true for unbiasedness.

Answer (score 4):

It is unbiased, let's see:  Let the linear model be $Y=X\beta +e$, in matrix form, with $E e=0$ and the variance-covariance matrix of the errors $e$ be $\Omega$.  We use for weights the matrix $W$. Then the weighted linear least squares estimator is
$$
   \hat{\beta} = (X'WX))^{-1}  X'WX Y
$$
and we can calculate its expectation as
$$
    E \hat{\beta} = (X'WX)^{-1} X\cdot W E Y = (X'WX)^{-1} X\cdot W X\beta =\beta
$$
and you can observe that the variance-covariance matrix $\Omega$ do not play any role in the computations!

Of course, if the weight matrix $W$ is estimated from the data in some way, then the above analysis is inadequate! This website  [Engineering Statistics Handbook](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmd/section1/pmd143.htm)
discusses this problem, and gives references.  Scroll down to "Disadvantages of weighted least squares".  Their advice is:

> It is important to remain aware of this potential problem, and to only
>   use weighted least squares when the weights can be estimated precisely
>   relative to one another [Carroll and Ruppert (1988), Ryan (1997)].